# Listen to Multiple Element Events in Angular 7

Tags: jquery, angular, dom, listener

I am new to Angular so forgive me if this is simple, but I can not find an answer anywhere. I'm trying to create an onblur listener for multiple DOM elements. Something similar to jQuery's "on". 
i.e.

```
$('.someclass').on('blur',function(e){
   some action affecting all matching elements.
});
```

Is this just not possible with Angular? Do I have to make a function call from each individual element?

Comment: for which element your trying to listen onblur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to attach eventListeners to elements is with the use of directives through which you can utilize  @HostListener and @Hostbinding that angular ships with.

Comment: As I understand it that still is just a listener for a single element correct?

Comment: It is actually reusable so for instance you can attach it as an attribute to several elements even on the same page and it works for each of them

Comment: I understand that it works for custom components, but on a standard input wouldn't it be similar to something like <input (blur)="function($event)">? What I was hoping for was a way to hook onto a group of elements (or better yet a top level element) and attach a listener to multiple elements at once.

Comment: Which directives do very well you can actually write standard jQuery codes in directives